# Submit a contact form and write to a separate class Java

Tags: java, forms, class, jframe, jbutton

This is my first time to post so i will say i am learning java and struggling i have to create a program that ask for three pieces of information and writes it to a class. Every example i have referenced to try to get it to work has not worked. 
Here is my code any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        interfath screen = new interfath();
        screen.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        screen.setSize(600,600);
        screen.setVisible(true);
    }
}

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class interfath extends JFrame {
    private JTextField item1; // 
    private JTextField item2; // 
    private JTextField item3; // Header
    private JTextField item4; // Instructions
    private JTextField item5; // First Name,
    private JTextField item6; // Text Box for First Name
    private JTextField item7; // Last Name
    private JTextField item8; // Text Box for Last Name
    private JTextField item9; // Phone Number
    private JTextField item10; // Text Box for Phone Number

    public interfath() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        item3 = new JTextField("Project ++ 2.0.5.10.20.34", 20);
        item3.setEditable(false);
        item3.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 20));
        item3.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        add(item3);

        item4 = new JTextField("Please fill out the following form and submit.", 60);
        item4.setEditable(false);
        item4.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.ITALIC, 12));
        item4.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        add(item4);

        item5 = new JTextField("First Name.",40);
        item5.setEditable(false);
        item5.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.ITALIC, 12));
        item5.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        add(item5);

        item6 = new JTextField("", 15);
        add(item6);

        item7 = new JTextField("Last Name.",40);
        item7.setEditable(false);
        item7.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.ITALIC, 12));
        item7.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        add(item7);

        item8 = new JTextField("", 15);
        add(item8);

        item9 = new JTextField("Phone Number.",40);
        item9.setEditable(false);
        item9.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.ITALIC, 12));
        item9.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        add(item9);

        item10 = new JTextField("", 15);
        add(item10);
    }
}
```

Comment: what does 'writes it to a class' means? Where is your logic that actually does the write? Consider looking at examples of event handling in swing.

Comment: "*Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must **include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error** and the **shortest code necessary** to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers*" - [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) I suggest cleaning up your post before people start downvoting/vote to close

Comment: When i mean write it to a class what it is suppose to do is

Comment: It is suppose to be a form requiring three pieces of data. first name, last name, and phone number. There is also suppose to be a submit button. When the submit button is pressed it is suppose to store the data in a file. It is also suppose to have a class to store the the user input. the class for the user input should handle data storage, when the the data is saved it should create an object within the class.